# R - Issues with double precision while writing to an excel file

Tags: r

I have multiple columns in a data frame called 'export', some of which are numeric with double precision.

```
class(export)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

When I write down the table using the following code, my excel file has values such as 13.0000000000001, 11, 3.9968E-14

```
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(export), file="test.xlsx", sheetName="test", row.names=FALSE)
```

I'm trying to get certain columns to show only the pure integer value and certain columns to show only one decimal.

I did try to define some of the columns as integer.

```
export$col1<-0L
```

But, it doesn't seem to work. I assume it's because I process this column later on using the group_by and summarize functions of the dplyr package which seems to be turning these columns into double again.

My question is how do I get one column to write as an integer and some other columns as a number with only one decimal? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: `mtcars[5:7] <- Map(round, mtcars[5:7], c(1, 2, 0))` or `mtcars[5:7] <- Map(as, mtcars[5:7], c("integer", "integer", "double"))`.  Pick your poison.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks!